# How to debug and fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/mzPxN/

am I trying to use the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/) to sort the columns.

**Problem**

Clicking on 'N' sorts the number column just fine.

Clicking on 'Signed' also sorts the checkbox column fine, but if you un-check one of the check boxes, they are not sorted correctly any longer.

The trick seams to be to add `0` and `1` when the checkbox is clicked using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912957/jquery-tablesorter-sort-by-column-having-input-elements/1913041#1913041)

```
<td>
    <span class="hidden">1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y">
</td>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tableid input').click(function() {
         var order = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
         $(this).prev().html(order);
    })

})
```

and using [this](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/10/24/Checkbox-Parser-and-Bug-Fix-for-jQuery-TableSorter-Plugin.aspx) as sorting algorithm

```
ts.addParser({
        id: 'input',
        is: function(s) {
            return s.toLowerCase().match(/<input[^>]*checkbox[^>]*/i); ;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            var integer = 0;
            if (s.toLowerCase().match(/<input[^>]*checked*/i)) {
                integer = 1;
            }
            return integer;
        },
        type: "numeric"
    });
```

But I am getting the error `not well formed`.

Have I implemented it correctly html and JQuery wise?

And if so, how do I debug and fix it?

Comment: where are you getting the error? Also did you not mean `$(this).next().html(order);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to have a fancy formatter or anything:

see my edit of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgMZ9/

put the span before the checkboxes :)

by default, it will look at whatever text comes first in the field, which is going to be your 0 or 1, and sort on that :)

Comment: If I un-check 4991, the it still sort as if is is checked. Does this happen for you too?

Comment: right of course, that's b/c i commented out :  $(this).parents("table").trigger("update");

my bad, leave that in, and it'll work a-ok

Comment: @Patricia : Great! So now that the extra complexity of the sorting algorithm is needed. What does it do?

Comment: not sure what you mean,   tablesorter will look at the data, see that it is a number, and sort on that :)

Comment: @Patricia : I was just under the impressing that `$.tablesorter.addParser` was needed in order to sort columns with checkboxes =) Is it because `$.tablesorter.addParser` looks directly at the checkbox value, and therefore not need the `span` trick?

Comment: having the span infront makes it so you don't need the addParser :)  number and text sorting is built into tableSorter.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden span in your case is after so change

```
$(this).prev().html(order)
```

to

```
$(this).next().html(order)
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzPxN/1/)