# Jquery sort table column by checkbox state

Tags: jquery, sorting, checkbox, state

I have a datatable that has a column called Waive Fee with checkboxes. The column needs to be sortable, i.e. when the column header is clicked, all the checkboxes that are checked needs to bubble up or bubble down. Is there a way in Jquery to do this, like calling a function on mouse event on the header and then some logic inside this function.

Please advise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple and lightweight plugin:
[sortElements plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/sortElements/)
Instructions and examples here:
[article with instructions](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)

It sorts elements in list

Comment: Although I was looking for a simple custom function, this plugin should work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can something like a table sorter plugin in jquery http://tablesorter.com/docs/  and you can use the approach to use it with checkboxes, in this link

[Jquery Tablesorter - sort by column having <input> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912957/jquery-tablesorter-sort-by-column-having-input-elements)